# How to split a column?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I would like to see if I can split a column in spark dataframes. Like this,

```
Select employee, split(department,"_") from Employee
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT explode(split(str, '_'))
```

Or this:

```
SELECT split(str, ' ')[0] as part1, split(str, ' ')[1] as part2
```

Comment: This helped me, but for the fact that I had a '.' as a delimiter and that needed escaping. Took some time to figure out why it didnt work, hence putting it in here -  SELECT split(str,'\\.'))[0] as source

Comment: Ridiculous as this is, I had to use '\\\\.' to escape the period. '\\.' didn't work (in Apache Zeppelin)

Comment: Is it possible to split on the first ' ' only?